# "Не изданными" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

> Эти книги так и остались не изданными.

Не слитно или раздельно?

Comment: Перечитайте написанное и вникните в смысл:  "не слитно или раздельно".

Comment: Все же поняли как надо. (Можно "придраться" и к этой фразе.) Надо было НЕ в кавычки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Эти книги так и остались неизданными.*
 Остались (какими?) неизданными — отглагольное прилагательное: нет зависимых слов, нет противопоставления с союзом *а*, отрицательных слов, можно заменить синонимом "забытыми", следовательно, пишется слитно.

Раздельно было бы причастие: *Эти книги так и остались никем не изданными.*